# How to get input value when changed by user

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I have a form where when user can enter value and then use tab indexing to move to the next input text box. When moving the to the next text box, the value of previous text box should be updated to a bean and at the same time I want to get the value from that bean. I tried few things but no luck. I am also not sure whether my approach is right. I think something is wrong with my set property. Please advise.

```
<%String area = "locality";%>
<input type="text" id="area" class="form-control" placeholder="Area"  value="<%=area%>" name="areaname" />

<script >
  $("#area").blur(function() {
    <jsp:useBean id="profcontact" class="com.get.ProfileFormContact" >
    <jsp:setProperty name="profcontact" property="area" value="${param.areaname}" />
    </jsp:useBean>
    $("#area").val("<jsp:getProperty name="profcontact" property="area" />");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: NO error thats the problem

Comment: can you get the value of #area after the operations?

Comment: You're confusing server-side code with client-side code.  The `<jsp:useBean/>` and `<jsp:setProperty/>` tags are evaluated on the server side - before the client even has a page to render.  If you want server-side beans to be updated by user activity from the front end, you need to either submit a form to load a new page, or use ajax.

Comment: @Tap Oh Ok then ajax it is